# Installing a wall vent when stud blocks the opening?

Tags: framing, vent

I'm installing a rear duct range hood and need to open a ~4"x18" hole through the exterior wall.  A 2x6 stud blocks the hole.  I plan to cut the stud and place a header, jack studs, and sill around the hole.

Do the jack studs need to extend all the way to the bottom plate or can they just be screwed into the king stud? (there is some wiring that would need to pulled back for the jack stud to reach the bottom plate)

Answer (score 1):

Exterior walls are load bearing walls. You can place a header over jack studs to bridge the overhead load to the bottom but for that to work properly the jack studs do need to go all the way down to the lower plate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Its a single stud.  Are there alternatives to jack studs that could be used?  I've seen articles where joist or header hangers were used instead of jack studs.

Comment: The problem with header hangers is that they transfer extra load to the existing single king studs that may or may not be over and above their designed to capabilities. This is why the conventional solution applies two jack studs to the base plate when there have been one or two studs cut out for a vent, door or window opening.